# $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest() does not raise error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing

My test setups a http request but I do not execute $httpBackend.flush(). Here is the test:

```
describe("Unit: Testing Services", function() {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('EmsWeb.Services'));
    describe("Unit: DalService", function () {
        var $httpBackend, dalService, appModel;
        beforeEach(inject(function ($q, _$httpBackend_, AppModel, DalService) {
            dalService = DalService;
            appModel = AppModel;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $httpBackend.when('POST', '../api/ModuleApi/GetModules').respond({ userId: 'userX', 'A-Token': 'xxx' });            
            appModel.context.company = { code: 'LPL' };
        }));

        describe("canceling request should fail", function () {             

            it('checks request should be canceled ', function () {
//              $httpBackend.expectPOST('../api/ModuleApi/GetModules');
                var returnedData;
                var callBackFn = function (data) {
                    returnedData = data;
                };
                dalService.getModules('senderIdentifier', appModel.context, callBackFn, callBackFn);
            });

        });

        afterEach(function () {
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });
    });
```

I expected `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();` to raise an error hence there was no call to `$httpBackend.flush()`.

I also tried to add `$httpBackend.expectPOST('../api/ModuleApi/GetModules');` but it did not make a difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest() will not raise any error regarding "Unflushed requests" unless the $http request is sent.
Things will become more clear if you shared DalService and what is getModules in that service doing.